# Output signal is being attenuated after the Biquad filter direct Form 1, why?

Tags: stm32, filter, digital-filter

Thought this would deserve a separate post on its own.

What's going on is that I finally got my low pass digital filter working on the [STM32H753ZI](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enCA841CA841&sxsrf=ALeKk0181J_yj10LYaGo5FVNDbOKMr78Qg%3A1602789035623&ei=q56IX_2-JZH5tAbGzr2YAw&q=stm32H753zi&oq=stm32H753zi&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzICCAAyBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB46BAgAEEdQvxhYvxhg9xxoAHACeACAAWCIAWCSAQExmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi9wPi4prfsAhWRPM0KHUZnDzMQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) using the [PMODI2S2](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/pmod/pmodi2s2/reference-manual) peripheral and I noticed the output signal is extremely low ~340mVpp this is after the biquad filtering. If I take out the low pass filtering the output signal then raises to around ~600mVpp.

What's causing this phenomenon? The digital filter bode plot says the gain from very low frequencies up to the cut off is 0dB so I dont understand whats going on. The only thing I can think of is the biquad filter is causing an attenuation perhaps?

Analog Filter: \$ LPF_{Analog}=\frac{3.94e07}{s^2+8889s+3.94e07}\$

[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JCTN.png)

Digital Filter: \$ LPF_{Digital}=\frac{0.00102z^2 +0.002041z+0.00102}{z^2-1.908z+0.9116}\$, using tustin

[image]

Pictures:

Input signal(yellow) from wave gen and output signal(green) after the Biquad filter
[image]

Input signal(yellow) from wave gen and output signal(green) passthrough with the peripheral no digital processing
[image]

Bode plot from Oscilloscope with the biquad filter:
[image]

CODE:

```
#define ARM_MATH_CM7

#include "main.h"

#include "arm_math.h"


void init_Clock(void);
void init_I2S(void);
void init_Debugging(void);
void init_Interrupt(void);
void init_SpeedTest(void);

int32_t RxBuff[4];
int32_t TxBuff[4];
uint8_t TC_Callback = 0;
uint8_t HC_Callback = 0;

char uartBuff[8];
 float32_t iir_coeffs[5] = {0.00102f, 0.002041f, 0.00102f, 1.908f, -0.9116f}; //B0, B1, B2, A1, A2
float32_t iir_mono_state[4];

float32_t Rx_Buff_f[4];
float32_t Rx_Buff_f_out[4];


arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 monoChannel;


void DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler(void) {

    if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_TCIF0)) != 0){
        DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CTCIF0;
        TC_Callback = 1;
    }

    else if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_HTIF0)) != 0){
         DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CHTIF0;
         HC_Callback = 1;

    }
}

int main(void) {

    init_Clock();
    init_I2S();
    //init_Debugging();
    init_Interrupt();
    //init_SpeedTest();
    arm_biquad_cascade_df1_init_f32(&monoChannel, 1, iir_coeffs, iir_mono_state);

  while (1)
  {

      if (HC_Callback == 1){

         // GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS3_HIGH;

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
              Rx_Buff_f[i] = (float32_t)RxBuff[i];
          }

          arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&monoChannel, Rx_Buff_f, Rx_Buff_f_out, 2);

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                TxBuff[i] = Rx_Buff_f_out[i];
            }

          HC_Callback = 0;

      } else  if (TC_Callback == 1){


        //  GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR3_LOW;


          for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
               Rx_Buff_f[i] = (float32_t)RxBuff[i];
            }

                  arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&monoChannel, &Rx_Buff_f[2], &Rx_Buff_f_out[2], 2);

                  for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
                        TxBuff[i] = Rx_Buff_f_out[i];
                    }



          TC_Callback = 0;

      }



  }

}
```

UPDATE 1:
As requested doing a spreadsheet of different frequencies and a block diagram and a physical setup to show you guys.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you remember from the previous discussions, check these first: `wavegen -> scope` (directly, nothing in-between); the probes must be DC coupled; no highpass or bandpass filter anywhere on the way there; passthrough means if you feed 1 Vdc at input, you get 1 Vdc times amplification at output.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen nothing of suspect, in software no HP or BP, in real hardware no HP or BP in oscilloscope setting nothing I cant see.

Comment: If you follow the Bode plot, a 100 Hz and a 1 kHz signal should have the about same amplitude, while a 10 kHz should be about 100x less. Also, DC at input should mean DC at output, do you get these correctly?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen At 1kHz signal is ~310mV at 10kHz signal is at 20mV. 1V DC input is 0VDC output. This is all after the biquad.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen in regards to your first comment, with nothing in between a direct connection to the wave gen with both channel, yes 1VDC is outputting 1VDC and so forth.

Comment: Then there is something between that acts like a highpass, it can't be otherwise. It's not the probe, if you say you can probe the wavegen for DC, directly. It's not the scope, since it's showing DC. It's somewhere in between the output of the wavegen and the probe. Do you have an eval board? If yes, does it have additional filtering? If not, is there some routine inside the uC that has something remotely similar to a highpass or bandpass?

Comment: https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/reference/pmod/pmodi2s2/pmodi2s2_sch.pdf The inputs of the PMOD have a bandpass, each. Are you using the jack inputs?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen No eval board, its a nucleo board. Not sure what in the uC can cause it though

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen ah, that could be it. I guess I gotta find the values and see what it is

Comment: A block + physical diagram might help explain with your probe measurements the loss of DC to simplify your problem

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 updated main post

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [jack I/O](https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/reference/pmod/pmodi2s2/pmodi2s2_sch.pdf) of the [Pmod I2S2](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/pmod/pmodi2s2/reference-manual), then there is a simple RC bandpass that will cripple your signal. You could try to bypass it either by probing directly after the filter -- straight on the input --, or bypassing the series caps with a wire -- which will still leave the parallel one to be a lowpass, but at higher frequencies (it looks like the -3 dB is at ~340 kHz, so you have plenty of bandwidth).

Be careful with bypassing, because those filters are not there without reason. You can't compensate in software since the series cap ensures you have 0 V at DC. You could add another cap in parallel to the 1 uF one, say 10 uF, and that will give you a boost of low frequencies up to 10 Hz for a fraction of a dB.

---

I tried to model the whole chain of filters and compare it to the readings in your table, this is the result:

[image: test]

`V(in)` is the output after the input filter, which is a simple resistive and capacitive divider, acting as a lowpass with -6 dB gain, `V(df1)` represents the output after the biquad (modelled as a direct form I), and `V(out)` is the output after the second external ADC uC (the `AUDIO OUT` in your block diagram). `V(test)` is a frequency piece-wise linear interpolation of the readings you provided (ignore the phase, you didn't read it, I only tried to mimic something close to `V(out)`).

The overall frequency response is fairly similar, slightly lower frequencies in the model, since it's an approximation -- there are various other I/O impedances that can affect the response. For now, let's assume they come close enough that they can be considered as having the same magnitude response. That leaves the gain. The RC divider at `V(in)` ensures an attenuation by 2, so 6 dB are accounted for. This can be verified by using a bypass on the biquad, which results in what you have seen before: a roughly 2x attenuation.

The rest of the dB are somewhere else. They cannot be in the biquad implementation, since the coefficients actually give a ~1.133 DC gain lowpass (slightly shelf, due to roundings). They cannot be somewhere on the STM board, since the bypass would have shown it. So that leaves the program, somewhere. At this point, I don't know the software part since I've never used an ARM, but in some of your comments you mention that increasing one of `RxBuff`, or `TxBuff`, results in an increased amplitude output. Maybe that's the key? Looking in the datasheet it only says:

> All I2S interfaces support 16x 8-bit embedded Rx and Tx FIFOs with DMA capability

However, if the cause is not found, it looks like it's only a matter of overall gain, which means that multiplying by a certain constant would solve the problem. After all, a multiply by `2.0f` of all the `B[0:2]` terms would be necessary to compensate for the RC divider at `V(in)`; making it `3.0f`, instead, should compensate for the rest of the gain.

Comment: then essentially I have to compensate it in software

Comment: @Leoc See the updated answer. If you keep the filter you will not get DC, ever, but you can get very low frequencies. If you remove or bypass it, you will, but there may be unforseen consequences. Flip the coin.

Comment: Interesting, I tried doing it in software for example just TxBuffer[i] = RxBuffer[i] << 2 and the output is now around ~1.32Vpp

Comment: @Leoc Does the same happen at 1 Hz? Or 1 Vdc?

Comment: at 1Hz is ~110mV

Comment: @Leoc You have to understand that what you consider "software compensation" is, in fact, the inverse of the input filter. That means infinite gain at DC. It also means adding another software filter that should be a like a PI controller. All this just to get the same output for very low frequencies? When you can modify it, as mentioned? Also, at his point, you've corrected your filter, and determined the cause for the lack of response. In order to correct that, you have a clear answer. Because a simple software gain will affect all the filter, and an inverse software filter will be ludicrous.

Comment: What doesnt make sense to me right now is that having the biquad have a gain of just 1 gives me an output voltage of 600mV, that make sense due to the RC bandpass network, however when using my digital filter is further attenuated to 340mV? My filter should have a DC gain of 1 so I should still see 600mV ?

Comment: @Leoc First make sure that your measurings are the same across the board: if you're using RMS at input, you have RMS output, if you have Vpp input, output is also Vpp, etc. Then, make sure that you're not taking just one single measurement at only one frequency, since you're effectively dealing with a bandpass now with a highpass at ~100 Hz, and a lowpass at biquad's fp. Therefore you should use at least 3 different frequencies: 50, 500, 5k. To test the passband gain, use 500 Hz, with the same mentions as in the first phrase.

Comment: Updated main post

Comment: Ok Missing from your block diagram is the impedance of all source and loads. the board has ~10k input V/2 divider going into 1uF into 7Mohm chip with a digital HPF , presumably also low f <10 Hz, so check those to isolate your problem in each stage.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you for the update, I was thinking the issue was also in the FIFO buffers. my idea was that since I was using a 32 bit buffer and the chip was giving me a 24 bit data I assumed the data was being cut off when being sent back via the TxFIFO. so I tried doing TxBuff >> 0 to shift the data back down by 1 byte to fit within a  24 bit buffer but it just attenuates the whole signal to almost 0. So it looks maybe the I2S chip has a 32 bit register as well. Still digging through but worst comes, ill do what you mention by multiplying the TxBuffer

Comment: @Leoc Be careful to not mix the bit depth -- the quantization resolution of the ADC representing the number of voltage levels with which it can encode an analog signal -- with the number of bits which is used for the data, which represents the literal number of bytes: 1 for `char`, 2 for `short`, etc. It may be better to simply multiply the biquad `B[0:2]` terms by the required amount (looks like `3.f`), rather than mess with the buffers, whatever consequence those may bring.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen fair enough, this is gonna drive me crazy as to why its being more attenuated but yea multiplying the biquad of B constants by 3f worked.

Comment: @Leoc I think it's a matter of an obscure register, or flag. Quite frankly, it's quite a behemoth of a uC to use for a simple biquad.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen hahahah yeah, just playing around with it. So you suspect is something within the setup of the I2S?

Comment: @Leoc It's strange, because multiplying by `2.f` is necessary to compensate for the RC divider at the input, which means there's a need for some extra multiply by `1.5f`, or close. Since your table uses Vpp for both input and output, it's not `sqrt(2)`, in case you read RMS. So, I don't know, but if I were to guess, I'd say it's something in the routines. But it can be that it's something else, entirely. But *only* if bypassing the biquad gives a 2x attenuation (which is what you said in one of your comments). Otherwise, I'd suspect whatever extra you have on the board with the uC.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen The funny thing theres nothing else on board just for the PMOD device. Yeah Bypassing the quad gave 2x attenuation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115177/discussion-between-a-concerned-citizen-and-leoc).