# Matlab Digital filter not working, how come?

Tags: stm32, filter, digital-filter

**Before reading any further, to give you on some insight on the output level of the oscilloscope picture's
the ~340mV green signal is normal. If you know me I posted a question as to why its 340mV but for sake of simplicity 340mV is normal in this case. So attenuation is not being seen here.**

trying to design some digital filters directly from matlab to be implemented in the [STM32H7](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h7-series.html) using the [CMSIS DSP library](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__BiquadCascadeDF1.html#gad0b680d1c529d941e939d265b3c6ae59)

I tried first doing a **butterworth low pass filter** with some criteria I made listed in the picture

[image]

Converted it to Direct-Form 1 and into second - order sections. Then generated to a .h header in single precision form as I am working with floats and not doubles.

Here are the coefficients

```
float32_t iir_coeffs[20] = {0.344617784f, 0.689235568f, 0.344617784f, 0.2994394898f, -0.6779106259f, // Biquad Stage 1
                            0.265586704f, 0.531173408f, 0.265586704f, 0.2307691127f, -0.2931158841f, // Biquad Stage 2
                            0.2259309888f, 0.4518619776f, 0.2259309888f, 0.1963121295f, -0.1000360623f, // Biquad Stage 3
                            0.2090389729f, 0.4180779458f, 0.2090389729f, 0.1816346198f, -0.01779049635f // Biquad Stage 4};
```

Once the coefficients where obtained, all I had to do in code was change the state variable length to 4*4 = 16 and number of stages to 4 as this is a 4 stage biquad filter implementation.

However this doesnt work! I have no idea as to why? There's no attenuation @ 20kHz should be -3dB down and at 40kHz should be a nice -100dB down but the picture says otherwise.

Oscilloscope pictures
[image]
[image]

[image]

CODE:

```
    #define ARM_MATH_CM7

#include "main.h"

#include "arm_math.h"


void init_Clock(void);
void init_I2S(void);
void init_Debugging(void);
void init_Interrupt(void);
void init_SpeedTest(void);

int32_t RxBuff[4];
int32_t TxBuff[4];
uint8_t TC_Callback = 0;
uint8_t HC_Callback = 0;

char uartBuff[8];
float32_t iir_coeffs[20] = {0.344617784f, 0.689235568f, 0.344617784f, 0.2994394898f, -0.6779106259f,
                            0.265586704f, 0.531173408f, 0.265586704f, 0.2307691127f, -0.2931158841f,
                            0.2259309888f, 0.4518619776f, 0.2259309888f, 0.1963121295f, -0.1000360623f,
                            0.2090389729f, 0.4180779458f, 0.2090389729f, 0.1816346198f, -0.01779049635f};

float32_t iir_mono_state[16];

float32_t inSample[4];
float32_t outSample[4];



arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 monoChannel;


void DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler(void) {

    if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_TCIF0)) != 0){
        DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CTCIF0;
        TC_Callback = 1;
    }

    else if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_HTIF0)) != 0){
         DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CHTIF0;
         HC_Callback = 1;

    }
}

int main(void) {

    init_Clock();
    init_I2S();
    //init_Debugging();
    init_Interrupt();
    //init_SpeedTest();
    arm_biquad_cascade_df1_init_f32(&monoChannel, 4, iir_coeffs, iir_mono_state);


  while (1)
  {

      if (HC_Callback == 1){

         // GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS3_HIGH;

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
              inSample[i] = (float32_t)RxBuff[i];
          }

          arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&monoChannel, inSample, outSample, 2);


          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                TxBuff[i] = outSample[i];
            }

          HC_Callback = 0;

      } else  if (TC_Callback == 1){


        //  GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR3_LOW;


          for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
              inSample[i] = (float32_t)RxBuff[i];
            }

                  arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&monoChannel, &inSample[2], &outSample[2], 2);


                  for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
                        TxBuff[i] =  outSample[i];
                    }



          TC_Callback = 0;

      }



  }

}
```

Update 1: To show you how the coefficients are presented

[image]

UPDATE 2:
Tried doing it one biquad at a time comparing it to the bode plot in matlab as I go up a biquad and it works up till the 4th stage. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Please don't paste same question to two sites without remark: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70965/matlab-filter-designer-not-working-how-come

Comment: Are you using 96 kHz sampling frequency? If you try other, higher frequencies, can you see some hint of a corner frequency?

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry, thought that was allowed. What do you mean without remark?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Correct Iam using a 96kHz sampling. 44kHz I see an attenuation

Comment: How did you account for frequency warping between S and Z domains? Bilinear transform?

Comment: @Leoc It sounds a lot like you're using twice the sampling frequency. Maybe you set some scaling that you forgot about?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I am not sure how matlab does it. All I did was use the command "filterDesigner" and started from there, once done it pops out coefficients for you. I am assuming it does do the bilinear transform pre warping for you, as I tested this in a bode plot and seems all good

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Interesting, maybe first time using this GUI. I just tried with a 1st order filter and it worked pretty well. Updated the main post. Might have to click on the picture to see whats going on

Comment: @Leoc "Pretty well" is pretty meaningless, a matching cut-off is. If the 1st order matches Matlab, but the Butterworth doesn't, it means that the implementation of the latter is off, somewhere. Try a 3rd, or 4th order, that should have 2 2nd order stages. If that, too, is off, then it's somewhere in the number of stages, or states (maybe, I have no ARM to play with).

Comment: @Leoc It's looking more and more like it's the way the filter is implemented when there are more than 1 2nd order stage. Last time you said you wanted to ask on heir forums. Did it help? I see you are instantiating a `monoChannel` `struct`, which is supposed to hold the states vector. Are those updated in `arm_biquad_cascade...` automatically, or do they need to be set manually? Also, try to delete redundant comments to avoid cluttering (for ex. yor last 3 comments can be deleted).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I updated the post saying stages from 1 - 3 worked, however when stage 4 gets implemented its not working as intended. Still waiting on a response from the forums. Correct the struct is suppose to hold the state vectors, indicate how many stages and points to the coefficients. I am not entirely sure if they do get updated via the arm_biquad_cascade function, read the library many times no mentions about it. I would imagine as one of the parameters for the arm_biquad_cascade is the struct that points to the state vectors and coefficients 1/2

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen 2/2 The funniest part, before all this I used this website https://arachnoid.com/BiQuadDesigner/ to implement a HP, LP and Peak filter and it worked perfectly, I am curious if I add another filter for the 4th stage would it stop working. If it doesnt then maybe its how matlab spits out its coefficients then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115351/discussion-between-a-concerned-citizen-and-leoc).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try scaling the input and the output?
The [documentation of the arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32](https://arm-software.github.io/CMSIS_5/DSP/html/group__BiquadCascadeDF1.html) mentions:

> The frequency response of a Biquad filter is a function of its coefficients. It is possible for the gain through the filter to exceed 1.0 meaning that the filter increases the amplitude of certain frequencies. This means that an input signal with amplitude < 1.0 may result in an output > 1.0 and these are saturated or overflowed based on the implementation of the filter. To avoid this behavior the filter needs to be scaled down such that its peak gain < 1.0 or the input signal must be scaled down so that the combination of input and filter are never overflowed.

Depending on your input / output format, maybe you can use arm_q31_to_float / arm_float_to_q31.

Comment: Welcome! :-) (a) I think you meant arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f3**2** not arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f3 - yes? I've fixed that typo. (b) To comply with site rules here, a link must be given to any text / images / photos which are included from elsewhere. I think I've found the best link for the documentation you quoted. If you think another source is better, you can edit your answer to change the link I used. (c) FYI, the site standard here for quoted text is the "blockquote" (`>`) so I used that. Some editing docs are [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help). I hope that helps :-)

Comment: Your answer not only does not address OP's problems (why there is no corner frequency, not [why there is attenuation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/527594/95619)), but you are also pointing towards a function that is not relevant to OP's case, since what you are talking about is for *fixed-point* arithmetic (`_q15` and `_q31` versions), not *floating-point*, (`_f32`, which is what OP is using).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution,

The sampling rate is actually somehow ~192kHz, I'll have to take a look at this as to how it became that.

Tried creating Biquad coefficients for **192kHz Sampling rate** and everything worked as I noticed which was pointed out by 'a concerned citizen' that my Fc was at ~40kHz which is doubled used 192kHz instead of 96kHz and boom.

Currently working with a 8th Order butterworth IIR low pass filter.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just double checked the code, I should be on 96kHz unless the Fws is actually = Fw*2. Right now the SPI is clocked at  98.34004MHz. SPI Clock / (256*(2*2)+0) =~96kHz according to data sheet, but clearly something is off here

Comment: It may be your I2S config. A 2 channel stereo 96kHz sampling rate gives 192kHz samples per second, so you better be sure that you are receiving and processing a single channel instead of 2 channel stereo buffer.

Comment: @Justme I dont know where in the I2S config it says mono though, I believe its doing 2 channel. Its  just kinda deceiving in retro spec with the data sheet as it says FWS = Sampling rate. I setup my FWS = 96kHz shouldnt that be the sampling rate?  I guess its 192kHz. I gotta bring it down Fws = 48kHz I guess..

Comment: @Leoc When I said "check your fs", I mean really check your fs, not just by looking at what you think you had to set in order to get the correct prescaler, but with the oscilloscope, as well. And now the question comes: why did the single 2nd order stages work?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen no, you're right I oversaw it. Kinda confusing thinking in the datasheet it tells you Fws = is sampling rate however thats for the stereo channel. I do apologize big over sight by me